# VBA, Range Column + 1

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to increment my column by one in my range. People are saying to use `.Cells` for this, but I am getting an error. `Type mistmatch`. How can I increment my column of `nameColumn` Variable by 1?

```
sh.Range(sh.Cells(lastR1, nameColumn + 1), sh.Cells(lastR1, lastCol)).AutoFill _
   Destination:=sh.Range(sh.Cells(lastR1, nameColumn + 1), sh.Cells(lastR, lastCol))
```

name column variable:

```
nameColumn = Split(.Find(Sheets("Input").Range("A2"), .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, _
        xlWhole).Address, "$")(1)
```

Comment: Is `nameColumn` a `String`? It shouldn't be.

Comment: yes it is a string.

Comment: `sh.Cells(lastR1, nameColumn).Offset(,1)`. Or show us how you are determining `nameColumn`, probably better to work with the column index.

Comment: you cannot add `1` to as string.

Comment: Added how I am determining nameColumn

Comment: `colNumber = .Find(Sheets("Input").Range("A2"), .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, _
        xlWhole).Column`. Working with the column letter is clunky.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Looks like your `Offset` suggestion worked too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with the column letter is clunky. You can't add `1` to a column letter.

Use the column index instead:

```
Dim foundCell As Range
Set foundCell = .Find(Sheets("Input").Range("A2"), .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)

If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
    Dim colNumber As Long
    colNumber = foundCell.Column
Else
    ' not found, throw error or alert user...
End If
```

Then you can easily do math with the column number, i.e. `colNumber + 1`.